# iOS - Call ended notification

Tags: ios

don't know if it's possible, but I have an app that prompts for a number to call. Then the "phone app" is called and the call goes on as usual

After the call ends I would like to trigger an event that makes the user "rate" the call made, always inside this app. I don't need to store any info from the call just done, since the call was already triggered from my app, so I already have the number

Is there a way to trigger those kind of events in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `CTCallCenter` and add a `callEventHandler` to be notified about state changes to the call.